# How to set "sudoers" in nsswitch.conf on Solaris-11

Tags: ldap, sudo, solaris-11, nsswitch.conf

I am doing this on Solaris 11.
When i open '/etc/nsswitch.conf' i see this -

```
...
sudoers:  files
...
```

I would like to change this to -

```
...
sudoers:  files ldap
...
```

I tried editing the file directly, but when i reboot host, changes are lost.
I tried using svcfg, but that didnt work -

```
root@solaristhost:/# svccfg
svc:> select name-service/switch
svc:/system/name-service/switch> setprop config/sudoers = "files ldap"
Type required for new properties.
svc:/system/name-service/switch> exit
```

Is there some way to set the 'sudoers' value in nsswitch permanently using the svccfg command or some other command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session you quote has a clue in the error message

> Type required for new properties.

It looks like you're missing a required type parameter and the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1455/c8switch-18904.html) has more information

```
# svccfg -s system/name-service/switch  
svc:/system/name-service/switch> setprop config/host = astring: "files dns nis"
svc:/system/name-service/switch> quit
```

Note the `astring:` type ...

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Now when i do 'listprop config/sudoers' i can see "files ldap".
But this value is still not reflected in '/etc/nsswitch.conf'. It still reads 'sudoers:  files'.
Are these changes made with svccfg supposed to reflect back in nsswitch.conf?

Comment: @QuestMonger: I've no idea I just read the docs - I don't have much to do with Solaris these days.

Comment: np. i found another way to do this. using nscfg - http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/archives/7452-Solaris-11-features-nscfg.html

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the missing type parameter, note also that the property in the service configuration is named 'sudoer', not 'sudoers'. Also, it is necessary to refresh the service after changing its configuration.

```
# svccfg -s system/name-service/switch  
svc:/system/name-service/switch> setprop config/sudoer = astring: "files ldap"
svc:/system/name-service/switch> exit
# svcadm refresh system/name-service/switch
```